# Using CSS animation delay (flicker) with Dynamic text

Tags: css, animation, dynamic

The text I am animating from right to left is Dynamic (innerHTML) and comes from a Google Sheet. If I hack the problem with a long (3 sec) animation duration, the text does not briefly appear in the final position before the animation runs. If I correctly use animation delay, the dynamic text briefly appears, before disappearing, and then animating in.

Is there a way to hide this text, prior to the animation running, so I can properly use delay. (it is hidden in the JS until the dynamic data is available).

```
#container {
position:relative;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 21px;
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 250px;
border: 1px solid #999;
overflow: hidden;
}
#loader {
text-align: center;
line-height: 250px;
}
#content > div {
position: absolute;
}
 #animation_container {
 position:relative;
  top:0;
left:0;
z-index:-100;
}
#headline, #subline {
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 26px
}


 #headline {
width:100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
-moz-animation-duration: 4s;
-webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
 -moz-animation-name: slidein;
 -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
     }
     @-moz-keyframes slidein {
        from {
           margin-right:100%;
           width:300%
        }
        to {
           margin-left:0%;
           width:100%;
        }
     }
     @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
        from {
           margin-right: 100%;
           width:300%
        }
        to {
           margin-left:0%;
           width:100%;
        }
     }    


 #subline {
 font-size: 23px;
 top: 90px;
 left: 15px;
 }
 #content.show {
 display: block;
 }
 #content.hide, #loader.hide {
 display: none;
 }
#loader.show {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you include all the HTML and CSS to reproduce the issue here?

Comment: The issue is the text appears when the dynamic content from the sheet is available. The content is dynamic because it can be targeted by Metro Code. Then it disappears after animation delay, and then proceeded to slidein from outside the container. I think the solution will end up being a hack of some sort.